# What is the surface integral of hemisphere?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Calculate the integral $∫ ∫_{Y}z dS$  if Y is the part of the conic
> surface $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ where z is between 0 and 1.

So this is what I did: $z = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and then I used spehere's coordinates and got z to $z=2\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}$ and my area elemnent or whatever it is called is given by $r^2\sin(\theta)$ and then I multiplied this by z and parted the integrals. I for some reasons think that I don't need to take r as the variable(I saw a similar quation where someone just took r as a constant, don't understand why and if I can do that here). This means my variables are theta and phi and the bounds are $0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}2$ and $0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$. First of all I don't know if I have done right so far so correct me if I'm wrong but otherwise how in the hell am I supposed integrate $\int 2\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)} = 2 \int \sqrt{\frac12 + \cos(2\theta)}$

**EDIT:** I accidentally posted the wrong question, this was the question my "solution" was for: Evaluate the surface integral $\int\int_{Y}zdS$ when Y is the upper half of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, i.e. the part where z ≥ 0.

Comment: $\pm \cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$

Comment: $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ne \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\ne2\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}.$ And $r$ is not constant. And you should calculate $dS$ (with cyclindric coordinates, more appropriate here than spheric).

Comment: Do you see any spherical symmetries in the integrand? If not then it is not to be expected that spherical polar coordinates will help

Comment: Sphere?  What sphere?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork OMG no, it was a wrong question I copy and pasted here and my answers is absolutely not for this question. What do I do now? Repost it or edit it? People have already answered here so editing might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First see that the surface is $z=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=f(x,y)$ .

Then the surface area element $dS$ when projected to the $x,y$ plane would be $\sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^{2}+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^{2}}\,dxdy$

Which is equal to $\sqrt{1+(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}})^{2}+(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}})^{2}}\,dxdy=\sqrt{2}\,dxdy$

So the integral is $\int_{D}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\cdot\,dx\,dy$ where $D$ is the disk $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$

Now use polar coordinates to get $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{2}\cdot r\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{2\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}$

**EDIT** :-
Well as per the question that you want to ask , see that now $z=\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}=f(x,y)$ .

So again, the surface area element can be calculated as ,

$\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}$

So the surface integral over the $x,y$ plane now becomes,

$$\iint_{D}\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\cdot\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}\,dx\,dy$$ where $D$ is the disk $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4$ .

$$=\iint_{D}2\cdot\,dxdy=2\cdot\text{Area of disk}=2\cdot(\pi 2^{2})=8\pi$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am kind of confused, why are you ignoring the 4 in step one because I get$\sqrt{\frac{3x^2+3y^2+4}{4-x^2-y^2}}$

Comment: @Need_MathHelp which $4$ are you referring to?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp $z^{2}=4-x^{2}-y^{2}$ . So $|\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|=\frac{x}{z}$ for $z$ in the upper hemisphere. So you'll get $\sqrt{1+(\frac{x}{z})^{2}+(\frac{y}{z})^{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{4}{z^{2}}}=\frac{2}{z}$ as the surface element.

Comment: I meant when I partial differentiated I got $\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4-x^2 - y^2}}$ and $\frac{2y}{\sqrt{4-x^2 - y^2}}$. When I raise it to 2, I get $\sqrt{\frac{4x^2+4y^2}{4-x^2 - y^2}+1}$ but you got $\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4-x^2 - y^2}+1}$

Comment: $2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2x $ . You are missing the $2$ that comes with the $z$. (Or in otherwords , the $\frac{1}{2}$ that comes due to the square root) . The partial should be $\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}}$

Comment: I see in that case I understand but the last part tho, which disk are you referring to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145808/discussion-between-need-mathhelp-and-mr-gandalf-sauron).

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Obviously. If you integrate $1$ over a region then you just get the area of the region . I have said that $D$ is the disk $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4$ . It's a 5th grade formula that the area of circle is given by $\pi r^{2}$ .

Comment: @Need_MathHelp In any case, what other disk can I be possibly refering to? Projection of the surface area into the $x,y$ plane would obviously be given by the bottom of the hemisphere which is $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4$ .

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed that part. But wouldn't it be something like $4^2*{\pi}*2 = 32{\pi}?$. Because we take 2 out of the integral and then the double integral gives us the area D and then we multiply by 2?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Radius is $2$ lol and not $4$

Comment: Of course it is! I'm am done here lol. But anyways I really appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help out. Everyone has days when we are confused by obvious parts.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend solving this problem in terms of cylindrical coordinates. First, recall that the scalar surface integral is
$$ \iint_Sf\,dS=\iint_{\vec R}f(\vec R(u,v))|\vec N|\,du\,dv$$
where $\vec R(u,v)$ is the parametrization of the surface in terms of some variables $u,v$ and $\vec N$ is the normal vector. To solve this problem, let's first parametrize our cone in cylindrical coordinates. Recall that in terms of cylindrical coordinates
$$ x=r\cos(\theta), \qquad y=r\sin(\theta), \qquad z=z $$
so we see that the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $z=r$. Thus, we see that the cone can be parametrized as $\vec R(r,\theta)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),r)$ with $0\leq r\leq 1$ and $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. Now, we must calculate the normal vector, so do this we calculate the tangent vectors
$$e_r=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),1)$$
$$ e_\theta=(-r\sin(\theta),r\cos(\theta),0)$$
and therefore the normal vector becomes
$$\vec N= e_r\times e_\theta=(-r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),r)$$
with the resulting magnitude $|\vec N|=\sqrt{2}r$. Thus, we have all we need to solve this integral. We get
$$\iint_{\vec R}f(\vec R(r,\theta))|\vec N|\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r(\sqrt{2}r)\,dr\,d\theta=2\sqrt{2}\pi\left(\frac{r^3}{3}\right]_0^1=\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}.$$
Hope this helps! Also I am kinda notorious for arithmetic errors so please let me know if I make an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. But I accidentally posted the wrong question and my answers in my post is not really for this question, this was the question I was supposed to post. Calculate the surface integral $∫∫_{Y} z dS$ when Y is the upper half of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$, i.e. the part where z ≥ 0. Would you mind helping me or at least giving me tips? Am I allowed to repost another question but with the same answers? Again I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Well you should include it in your edit (Don't remove the question that you "accidentally" asked) . Instead just add the question that you wanted to ask below it . In any case, the method I used is still applicable and you can recover the answer from it. I'll edit my answer accordingly . Please post your edit.